# SassError: Undefined variable

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a variable file that has two definitions of themes I want to overwrite:

_vars.scss

```
body {
  $bg-color: #fff
}
body.theme-dark {
  $bg-color: #333
}
```

I´m calling the variables in my Angular button component:

button.scss

```
@import '_vars.scss';

.button {
  background-color: $bg-color;
}
```

But I´m getting the following compiling error:

**SassError: Undefined variable.**

**background-color: $bg-color;**

Whats is the right way to overwrite variables depending on my body theme class?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You define `$bg-color` depending on the theme, but never `$font-size-18`.

On a side note, I would consider to use [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) instead of SASS variables if I was in your shoes. [Codyhouse](https://codyhouse.co/blog/post/css-custom-properties-vs-sass-variables) have an interesting and easy to understand article about this, which also talks about color themes.

If you want to dig deeper into this topic you may want to read [this article](https://css-tricks.com/creating-color-themes-with-custom-properties-hsl-and-a-little-calc/).

Comment: Edited the question here haven´t see the mispelling.

Answer (score 0):

First of all variables inside scope valid only in that scope not universally. Now for your question see below :-

**_vars.scss**

Instead of making variables inside body scope create it in global scope.

```scss
$bg-color: #fff;

body {
  background-color: $bg-color;
}
```

and then import it in your **button.scss** *without underscore "_"*

```scss
@use "vars" as *;

button {
  background-color: $bg-color;
}
```